# Using values of a groups of objects to create an image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, image-classification

I have calculated the 90th percentile for each class of land cover using the reducer ee.Reducer.percentile([90]).group
The result is a group of objects and I don’t know how to use it.

[image: gropus of objects]

I would like to use the value of the calculated 90th percentile for each class to create an image so that each pixel, characterized by a type of landcover, has the value of the calculated percentile.

How can I do this?

This is the code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/df42e9c2ef50aec5dff3fb2fefb5edbd

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert your dictionary (i.e. the output of your grouped reduction) into a featureCollection with null geometry, this makes the outputs much easier to handle.

```
var NDVI90perc = NDVILandCover.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([90]).group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'landcover',
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e8
}).get('groups');
NDVI90perc = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List(NDVI90perc).map(function (dict) {
    // Convert the dictionary to properties of a feature (with no geometry)
    return ee.Feature(null, dict);
  })
);
print(NDVI90perc)
```

Once you have your featureCollection you can `.map()` over it in order to create one image for each land cover type and give it its associated p90:

```
var NDVI90percImageCol = NDVI90perc.map(function(feature){
  var lcClass = ee.Number(feature.get('landcover')).toInt()
  var p90 = ee.Number(feature.get('p90')).toFloat()
  return ee.Image(0).where(LandCover.eq(lcClass),p90).toFloat()
})
```

Finally you need to turn that imageCollection into a single image by calculating the sum:

```
var NDVI90percImage = ee.ImageCollection(NDVI90percImageCol).max().selfMask()
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, it's exactly what I need!

Comment: Great! Could you accept my answer? Thanks!